# Xamarin Google Map API Json not converting

Tags: c#, android, json, google-maps-api-3, xamarin

the problem is when I am testing the app and check

> Task.Run(() => this.LoadDataAsync(url)).Wait();

I get an error Newtonsoft cannot deserialize the current JSON Object. Anybody can see why is that?

I have used http://json2csharp.com/ to create the class for JSON.
The app works normally and returns lat lng on Google Map on another call.

```
string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=MYAPI IS HERE";
List<GoogleApiResponseJson> googleApiResponseJson = new List<GoogleApiResponseJson> ();

public async Task LoadDataAsync(string uri)
{
    string responseJsonString = null;

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try 
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
            responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            googleApiResponseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GoogleApiResponseJson>>(responseJsonString);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've got this class holding JSON:

```
public class GoogleApiResponseJson

{
    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }
public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public bool open_now { get; set; }
    public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string photo_reference { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

}

OnCreate call:

```
    public async void ApiCallCall ()
    {
        Task.Run(() => this.LoadDataAsync(url)).Wait();         
    }
```

Comment: Check the content of the HttpResponseMessage, my bet is Google is spitting an error as response and because that it can't be deserialized. If it's not an error post the response so we can see the Json model.

Comment: Forget it you're deserializing it wrong, change `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GoogleApiResponseJson>>(responseJsonString);` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleApiResponseJson.RootObject>(responseJsonString);`

Comment: Didn't help as GoogleApiResponseJson is a List and it's throwing an error during build

Comment: GoogleApiResponseJson is not a list, maybe the api returns a list, but if this is the cas then it must be `List<GoogleApiResponseJson.RootObject>`, but for my experience with google maps it usually returns a root object and that object contains a list of results (what you exactly have on the RootObject)

Comment: I get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.GoogleApiResponseJson.RootObject>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.GoogleApiResponseJson>

Comment: please post the actual JSON response

Comment: @Always_hungry man, change the declaration of googleApiResponseJson to match the type you're deserializing...

Comment: JSON response is too long to post...

Comment: @Gusman looks like this sorted the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the GoogleApiResponseJson class wrapped around all the other classes and Deserialize the RootObject(Not as a List) as shown below.

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseJsonString);
```

The RootObject has a List of Results that will be most of what you are looking for.